# How to convert the given Before Links to the After Links using a couple of lines of code in Java?

Tags: java, node.js, linked-list

```
Before:
       +----+----+
list-->|  1 |  / |
       +----+----+
       +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+
list2-> |  2 |  +----> |  3 |  +----> |  4 |  / |
       +----+----+    +----+----+    +----+----+
After:
           +----+----+      +----+----+    +----+----+
list 1---->| 4 |     +----> |  1 |  +----> |  2 |  / |
           +----+----+      +----+----+    +----+----+

          +----+----+ 
List2---->|  3 |  / |
          +----+----+
```

This is what I have :

```
list.next = list2.next.next // 4 -> 1
list = list2 // 4 -> 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
list2 = list.next.next.next.next // 3
list.next.next.next.next = null // 4 -> 1 -> 4 -> 2
```

I don't know if it is right? I am having trouble figuring out the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi @BetheGirly1 welcome to StackOverflow.
I think you're asking how to reverse a linked list in Java.

You can either pop all elements in the linked list off of the list and push them onto a stack then pop them off again (which would only be good if you know the list is only ever going to be small).

Otherwise, you can iterate through your (singularly) linked list with three variables. One holding the previous Node value, one holding the current and one holding the next, then switch write over the next value in the Node with the previous Node.

My Java is a bit rusty (you did tag this as Node.js, probably accidentally).

```
    // pass in the first node in the LinkedList, normally a LinkedList class knows the head. 
    public void reverse(Node head) {
        Node previous = null;
        Node current = head;
        Node nextNode = null;

        while (current.next != null) {
            nextNode = current.next;
            current.next = previous;
            previous = current;
            current = nextNode;
        }
    }
```